# Could you interpret these screen resolutions from Google Analytics?

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution

After choosing Macintosh in my Google Analytics stats and then choosing Screen Resolution as the secondary dimension, I get these numbers:

[image]

Which one of these are 15" Macbook Pro, 13" Macbook Pro, etc.

I'd like to know if the Retina screens are reported in their actual resolution. I don't see any stats for 2560x1600 and 2880x1800. Does this mean that these Retina screens are reported as 1280x800 and 1440x900 respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1440x900 is the native resolution for 15'' non Macbook Pros, and the given  (best/default) resolution for 15'' rMBP with *the pixel doubling effect taken into account, as it is.* The analytics don't distinguish between the two, so the most you can infer from the data is that the most common model is a 15'' Macbook Pro.

Comment: Technically, I could capture the device pixel ratio via a custom variable which would distinguish the non-Retina vs Retina 15" Macbooks :)